# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method methodName on channel channelName

Tags: ios, flutter, timer, background-service, foreground-service

At root where main() resides, I've been trying to  call MethodChannel and eventually call invokeMethod of it so that I can call one of my methods in the iOS platform code and get the results which in turn will be taken care of by a handler as follows:

```dart
const methodChannel = MethodChannel('iOSFlutterChannel');

Future<void> getDataFromPlatform() async {
  try {
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(methodCallHandler);
    await methodChannel.invokeMethod('getData'); // * Where the error occurs
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    debugPrint('${e.message}');
  }
}


Future<dynamic> methodCallHandler(MethodCall call) async {
  switch (call.method) {
    case 'abcdef':
      // Do something
      return Future.value('');
  }
}
```

However, whenever the program comes to the invokeMethod part, I get an error saying "`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getData on channel iOSFlutterChannel)`."

These pieces of code will not trigger an error when they are placed inside a StatefulWidget.

The reason why I put the methods at root is that there is a timer I would like to keep no matter where I am in the app.

What am I missing?

I've decided to use this package and followed its example as much as I can.

flutter_background_service | Flutter Package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example

My goal is that while keeping receiving results inside methodCallHandler, I can forward them back to a StreamBuilder of the page where the timer was started.

To recap the requirements,

- a single stateful widget page with start/stop button
- user can go any other pages and the app can go off foreground while the timer is on
- timer can constantly call invokeMethods like every seconds
- all results can be forwarded to the original stateful widget page

I've seen some example apps with a timer. But they are always a super simple single-page app. Not really like mine. How would you go about this?

**UPDATE**: I tried some other packages/examples, but the same "`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getData on channel iOSFlutterChannel)`" follows. So if I could pass this problem, it would be a big step forward to me. Allow me to reduce the scope of the question: **How do I call `MethodChannel.invokeMethod` at top level without getting the aforementioned error?**

Comment: Hi @yoppuyoppu, did you ever manage to find a solution to this? I have the same issue whenever some push notification tasks has to be performed from the top level

Comment: @blaffie No, I didn't. And I moved on to a non-Flutter project.